# What is the value of these bitcoin certifications that have popped up recently?

Tags: websites, learning, job

Are bitcoin related certifications viewed favorably amongst the bitcoin community? I work in a related field and I am interested in pursuing a certification to distinguish myself, but I'm not sure how valuable these things are.

For example the following organizations:

[CryptoCurrency Consortium](https://cryptoconsortium.org/certifications/CBP)

[Digital Currency Council](https://www.digitalcurrencycouncil.com/certification-learn-more/)

Answer (score 1):

It varies.

The first certification you posted, CBP, seems to be [broadly well-perceived](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2fztuk/crypto_currency_certification_consortium_become_a/). As for the second one, I cannot find anyone saying anything about it, besides that it exists.

> but I'm not sure how valuable these things are.

I'm not sure either. Similar to [security guard training companies](http://nypost.com/2013/04/10/security-guard-training-company-scammed-customers-during-financial-crisis-lawsuit/), these certification organizations are going to exist along a spectrum of legitimacy.

Personally, (and this is where we go from facts to opinions) I think the CBP test would be worth taking if you already have the knowledge to do so, but beyond that, you're probably better off with a certification in a related field, like RHCE.

Comment: Looking at the board of directors and advisers it seems like C4 is well-established. I know that Andreas M. Antonopoulos doesn't put his name on just anything.